# Is It possible convert PKCS7 to PkiPath with OpenSSL?

Tags: python, clojure, openssl, certificate

I'm trying to translate a code written in clojure to openssl (I want to use this instead of clojure), but I came across the following line of code:

```
(def cert-path-encoded (.getEncoded cert-path "PkiPath"))
(def cert-path-encoded-b64 (.encodeToString (java.util.Base64/getEncoder)
                                            cert-path-encoded))
```

With openssl I was only able to reproduce using pkcs7 encoding:

```py
import subprocess
with open('./certificado.pem', 'rb') as file:
    cert_p7b = subprocess.check_output([
        'openssl', 'crl2pkcs7', '-nocrl', '-certfile', file.name,
        '-out', 'certificado.p7b'
    ])
```

My question is: Is It possible convert pkcs7 or pem to pkipath like this code in clojure using openssl?

Answer (score 1):

Your Python code is using the `subprocess` module to run the `openssl` command with some parameters. The code expects a variable with the name `file` and it always converts the certificate to the file `certificado.p7b`.

The same can be expressed in Clojure using the `sh` function from the `clojure.java.shell` namespace. I've changed it a bit, so instead of taking a file, it just takes the *filename* and the output of the conversion is returned to the function by changing the `-out` parameter to `-`, which denotes the standard output.

To use it, I created a test self-signed certificate with:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

The code looks like:

```clj
(ns ssldemo.core
  (:use [clojure.java.shell :only [sh]]))

(defn convert-to-pkcs7 [filename]
  (let [result (sh "openssl" "crl2pkcs7" "-nocrl" "-certfile" filename "-out" "-")]
    (get result :out)))

(comment

  ;; Example call:
  (convert-to-pkcs7 "cert.pem")
  ;; outputs "-----BEGIN PKCS7-----\nMIIFmgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIFizCCBYcCAQ..."
  )
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. Sorry for that and thank you for your reply, but I need my certificate be coded in PkiPath and I don't want to do this in clojure, I want to do this in Openssl with python subprocess. Tell me if you understood

Comment: Hi, I understand it now. I had a quick look at the [OpenSSL wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org) and I couldn't find anything. I'm not an expert in certificates, but I found that PkiPath is a type of encoder [available on all Java implementations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/cert/CertPath.html), so maybe instead of launching OpenSSL, you can launch a Java program that performs the conversion?